# SVN Server occupying a lot of space

Tags: svn

I have created an SVN server long time back. 
I have been storing some binary files (doc files) along with codes.
After every edit size increases because SVN saves a new copy of binary file.
Now the svn is occupying a lot of space.

Q1. I want to delete all previous revision of the binary files, keeping previous revisions of my codes intact, how do I do that?

Q2. Also is there any setting in SVN where I can customize it? Like "for specific folder dont store more than 10 revisions".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to destroy data in subversion is to dump the repository to a file; run it through `svndumpfilter` and load it back again. svndumpfilter only works on paths, not revisions, however, so for your purpose, I'd recommend `svn export`ing your binaries folder, before doing the following:

```
svnadmin dump <repo root> > file.dump     
cat file.dump | svndumpfilter  exclude <repo path containing binaries> > file-new.dump
svnadmincreate <new repo root>
svnadmin load <new repo root> < file-new.dump
```

This will leave you with a copy of your repository, including full history, but without the offending path; and you'll see empty revisions in the history where commits to those paths happened. (There are some options to `svndumpfilter` to remove those, but in most cases you probably want to preserve the revision numbering.)

As for automating this, You could use a post-commit hook to script this process, but it's massively time consuming on large repositories. You'd be better off simply not storing binaries in SVN at all, if you don't need the history for them.

Answer (score 2):

i'm affraid you cant do it 'out of the box', what goes in is meant to stay.
you can remove files by dumping the repository, filtering files and importing it again - but it's a pain.

check this discussions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426056/why-isnt-obliterate-an-essential-feature-of-subversion), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560684/svn-obliterate).